# Kubernetes worker node only for a specific type of pod

Tags: kubernetes

I've a requirement where I want to schedule a specific type of pod on a particular node and no other types of pod should get scheduled on that node. For example,

Assuming that I've 3 worker nodes - w1, w2 and w3
I want pods of type(say POD-w2) should always get scheduled on w2 and no other type of pods should get scheduled on w2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, we have to taint the node as well as affinity by labeling the node. The required pod should tolerate the taint and satisfy the affinity also. By this way pod will get scheduled ONLY on the dedicated node.

example:

```
kubectl taint nodes <dedicated_node_name> dedicated=myservice:NoSchedule
```

```
kubectl label node <dedicated_node_name> dedicated=myservice
```

then use toleration and affinity in the deployment spec

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: dedicated
                operator: In
                values:
                - myservice
```

and

```
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: dedicated
        operator: Equal
        value: myservice
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a label type=w2 to worker 2.

Use node selector or node affinity to schedule required pods on that node.

For other pods use node anti affinity to prevent other pods getting scheduled on to the worker 2

Comment: I agree this will work, but the problem is for each of the other deployment I need to add anti affinity the deployment spec which is not desirable.

Comment: look at taint and tolerations. it would help. follow the link -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score 1):

To exclusively use a node for a specific type of pod, you should `taint` your node as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/). Then, create a `toleration` in your deployment/pod definition for the node taint to ensure that only that type of pod can be scheduled on the tainted node.

Comment: If I only use taint and toleration then chances are there that the pod might get scheduled to other worker nodes also.

Comment: That depends on how you specify your taints. The general rule of thumb is to use taints to specify a group of nodes that pods can/cannot schedule to; and to use `nodeSelector` for nodes to specifically schedule the nodes to.